# Scikit Learn the meaning of output **predict_proba** and **predict.**

Tags: python, scikit-learn, prediction

When using scikit learn for Logistic Regression, there are the codes:

```
print(sentiment_model.predict_proba(test_features[:2]))
print(sentiment_model.predict(test_features[:2]))
```

Output:

```
[[1.20150248e-04 9.99879850e-01]
 [9.99986356e-01 1.36436948e-05]]
[1 0]
```

I'm struggling to understand the meaning of output **predict_proba** and **predict.**
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In Scikit-Learn, `predict` returns the prediction (`0` or `1`, `False` or `True`), while `predict_proba` returns a certainty score for the prediction. The output of `predict_proba` is an array with the first element being an estimate of the probability that the instance is a `0` class (or `False` class), and the second element being an estimate of the probability that the instance is a `1` class (or `True` class). As such, the rows in the `predict_proba` output add up to one.

In your code, the first instance is a `1` class (whatever that was encoded to mean in your application), with a probability of `0.999879859`. In the second instance, however, the probability of it being a `1` class is small ( `0.00001364...`). Hence, it is a `0` class, with a probability of `0.99998635`).

Comment: Thank for your clarification